# Quartz.Net daily interval schedule

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net

does anyone know if the following is possible with a cron schedule or another schedule type ?

Interval in Minutes 5 
Daily between 1h30 and 23h00
Every second day

I tried DailyIntervalSchedule which comes close but without the every second day clause. I tried cron as well but failed because of the daily interval between 1h30 and 23h00.

Any help is really apreciated.
Thanks T4E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that the method I'm describing now may help you. You should define two triggers. These triggers should schedule with same job.

```
            // construct a scheduler factory
        IScheduler sched = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

        // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>().StoreDurably()
            .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1") // name "myJob", group "group1"
            .Build();

        sched.AddJob(job,true);

        string cron = "0 0/5 2-23 1/2 * ?"; // interval in minutes 5 2h00 and 23h00 every second day
        string cron1 = "0 30,35,40,45,50,55 1 1/2 * ?"; // 1h30 every second day

        // Trigger the job to run now, and then every 40 seconds
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithCronSchedule(cron)
            .ForJob(job)
            .Build();

       ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithCronSchedule(cron1)
                .ForJob(job)
                .Build();


        // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
        sched.ScheduleJob(trigger);
        sched.ScheduleJob(trigger1);

        sched.Start();
```